# Append dict at same time python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, append

I want to append elements to an empty dictionary in python.
For a current frame I am attributing two keys: 'ID' and 'Coordinates'.
My problem is when I am appending the values, e.g

```
df={}

for i in range:

  df[i]['ID'].append(ID.values)

  df[i]['coordinates'].append(coordinates.values)
```

The output is something like this

```
{'ID': [ID.values], 'coordinates': [coordinates.values]}}.
```

But what is supposed to get is something like this

```
{'ID': [ID.value], 'coordinate': [coordinate.value],
'ID': [ID.value], 'coordinate': [coordinate.value],...}
```

I need the code to do the append at the same time, so the first ID matches with the first coordinate, the second ID with the second coordinate, and so on.

Comment: You don´t need a dictionary, you need a list were _Each_ element is a dictionary with the `ID` and `coordinate` keys.

Comment: How/Where is *ID* declared?

Comment: After d={}, I forgot to define df[i]= {'ID': [], 'coordinates': [] }

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip` built-in function to transform the two arrays into an array of pairs, then call the `dict` function to generate your dictionary:

```
df = dict(zip(ID.values, coordinates.values))
```